# Nginx Redirect HTTP to HTTPS automatically for subdomains

Tags: nginx, https, redirect

I am trying to redirect all my traffic from `http` to `https` automatically. How can i do a 301 redirect to all my domain and subdomains?

This is NGNIX Config file

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/run/DigitalOceanOneClick/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name sprintsocial.io app.sprintsocial.io admin.sprintsocial.io;
#       return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    #listen   80;
    listen 443;
    root /home/rails/sprintsocial/public;
    #server_name _;
    server_name sprintsocial.io app.sprintsocial.io admin.sprintsocial.io;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/sprintsocial.io.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/sprintsocial.io.key;
    index index.htm index.html;
#    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

#    rewrite ^/(.*) https://app.sprintsocial.io/$1 permanent;
#    rewrite ^/(.*) https://admin.sprintsocial.io/$1 permanent;

    location / {
            try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
                    try_files $uri @app;
            }

     location @app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do this with:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=off;
    server_name sprintsocial.io app.sprintsocial.io admin.sprintsocial.io;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Please note that:

- `listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off` binds to both ipv4 and ipv6,
- `$host` variable comes from request, `$server_name` comes from `server` which handles the request, big difference
- it will be overruled by other `server` directives when `server_name` matches the request

Comment: Original answer might now work with ipv4, `ipv6only` flag is turned on since nginx 1.3.4.

Comment: When i try to visit `http://app.sprintsocial.io` its going to `https://sprintsocial.io` instead of `https://app.sprintsocial.io` any idea how to solve that?

Comment: It may be browser cache (301 is a permanent redirect), check with curl: `$ curl -I http://app.sprintsocial.io` - `Location` header should point to `https://app.sprintsocial.io`. It should work with any subdomain.

Comment: removing the server_name all together works fine :)